# Android : I have a toolbar with a sliding tab . Now how do I change data on my toolbar , when user changes the tab

Tags: android, toolbar, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have a toolbar with a sliding tab . Now how do I change data on my toolbar , when user changes the tab . The [SlidingTabLayout](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java) and [SlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java) are used . The onPageSelected is overidden in SlidingTabLayout.

toolbar_search.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
android:elevation="2dp"
android:theme="@style/Base.ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" >

<AutoCompleteTextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/autocomplete"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:hint=" Bus Service Number"
    android:textColor="#000" />
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

SearchByBusInfo.java(Main Activity)

```
public class SearchByBusInfo extends AppCompatActivity  {

// Declaring Your View and Variables

Toolbar toolbar;
ViewPager pager;
ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
SlidingTabLayout tabs;
CharSequence Titles[] = { "tab1", "tab2" };
int Numboftabs = 2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_by_bus_info);

    // Creating The Toolbar and setting it as the Toolbar for the activity
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles
    // fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
    adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), Titles,
            Numboftabs);

    // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true,
                                    // This makes the tabs Space Evenly in
                                    // Available width

    // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
        }
    });

    // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
    tabs.setViewPager(pager);

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    // noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}
```

ViewPageAdapter.java

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are
                        // Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is
                        // created
int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when
                // the ViewPagerAdapter is created

// Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in
// the class
public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, CharSequence mTitles[],
        int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
    super(fm);

    this.Titles = mTitles;
    this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

}

// This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    if (position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First
                        // tab
    {

        Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();

        return tab1;
    } else // As we are having 2 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1
            // so we are returning second tab
    {

        Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
        return tab2;
    }

}

// This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return Titles[position];
}

// This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return NumbOfTabs;
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by data? Title text?

Comment: Provide more details like a screenshot or something please...

Comment: @Antrromet menu items

Comment: @Hussein Added the code

Answer (score 1):

You can inflate a different menu in every fragment that you load.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main,menu);
}
```

where menu_main.xml can be something like that:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<item
    android:id="@+id/myAction"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/a_drawable"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

To listen to the Action events you have to override OnCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: Hi , I have to change the hint in autocompleteTextView inside the toolbar

Comment: I have edited my answer for getting just the autocompleteTextView from your fragment

Comment: Hi , it works . But it works only when the app is launched. But after that when I change the tab , the hint is not changed . I have 2 tabs . for first tab I set hint as "hint1" and for 2nd I set it as "hint2" . So when the app is launched , it sets the hint to "hint2" and after that no changes

Comment: You've put the code in every fragment right? Let's say fragment1 for the first tab and fragment2 for the second right? Try to put the code in onCreateView

Comment: Yes I did that . Both fragments have seperate code inside onCreateView

Comment: I think because no new instance of fragment is created when we change the tabs , and we are making changes in the fragments . So the change is not reflected

Comment: Yes you are right. You will have to do it from the OnPageChangeListener as suggested in another answer. That means in your activity

Answer (score 0):

you can always try this one if you are using `ViewPager` :

```
ViewPager mViewPager ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){
    ...
    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    switch(position){
    case 0 :
      // Do the changes for the 1st page here
    break;
    case 1 :
      // Do the changes for the 2nd page here
    break;
    }   

    }
    ...

   });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I tried that but does not work . Added the below code in onPageSelected :if (position == 0){
    
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
      .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    
    View v2= inflater.inflate(R.layout.toolbar_search,null);
          
          AutoCompleteTextView searchBar = (AutoCompleteTextView) v2.findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
          
          searchBar.setHint("Hint1");
   }